# Stochastic spread method for pairs trading by Elliot et. al (2005) - Kalman filter + EM algorithm in MATLAB, am I doing something wrong?

Tags: matlab, kalman-filter, trading

I am implementing the Stochastic spread method for pairs trading by Elliott et. al (2005).

The procedure consists of modeling the spread between two stocks, log(P1)-log(P2), as a mean reverting process, calibrated from market observations.

The hidden state process for the spread can be written like this:

x_{t+1} = A + Bx_t + Ce_{t+1}

The observation process is:

y_t = x_t + D*w_t

Both e_t and w_t are i.i.d. Gauusian N(0,1).

Elliott gives the Kalman filter equations in his paper, which I have implemented in my code for the updating step:

```
function [xt_t,st_t,xt_tm,kt,st_tm]=EMupdate(DATA_t,xt_t_m1,st_t_m1,A,B,C2,D2)
st_tm=B^2*st_t_m1+C2;
kt=st_tm/(st_tm+D2);
xt_tm=A+B*xt_t_m1;
xt_t=xt_tm+kt*(DATA_t-xt_tm);
st_t=st_tm-kt*st_tm;
```

where

`xt_t` is `x_{t|t}`

`xt_t_m1` is `x_{t-1|t-1}`

`xt_tm` is `x_{t|t-1}`

`st_t` is `s_{t|t}` (the MSE, denoted as P in e.g. Hamilton (1994))

`st_t_m1` is `s_{t-1|t-1}`

`st_tm` is `s_{t|t-1}`

`kt` is the kalman gain for time t

`DATA_t` is the observed data for time t, `y_t`

`A`, `B`, `C2`, `D2` are the estimated parameters (which I have estimated using the EM algorithm in another code).

This update step is done every time a new data point arrives. I am storing all the x's, s's and k's in vectors. I am supposed to compare `y_t` with `x_{t|t-1}`, and given a large deviation of the two, a trade should be initiated. However, the two follows each other very closely, and I am unsure whether I have done something wrong:

[image: signals]

Can someone see if I am doing wrong?
Please tell me if I should link more of my code.

UPDATE: My procedure: (P is the same as s above)

1. To generate the spread between two stocks, I take the difference between the log-prices: y=log(p1)-log(p2).
2. I set a training period of 252 days, where I estimate the initial parameters (`A`, `B`, `C2` and `D2`) using the EM algorithm. I implement the EM algorithm using all the data for the training period; that is y(1), y(2), ..., y(252) as well as initial guesses for `A`, `B`, `C2` and `D2`:

2a. I set `x_{1|1}=y(1)`. Furthermore I set the MSE, `P_{1|1}=D2`, my initial guess for D^2.

2b. I recursively calculate Kalman filters, x_{t|t}, x_{t+1|t}, P_{t|t}, P_{t+1|t} and k_{t} for all t=1...252 (the entire training period) using my initial guesses for `A`, `B`, `C2` and `D2`.

2c. After I have calculated the kalman filters for the entire training period, I (backward) recursively calculate Kalman smoothers for the entire training period as well: t=1...252. These are `x_{t|T}`, `P_{t|T}`, `P_{t,t-1|T}` and `j_{t}`.

I then compute the log-likelihood value and the updated values for `A`, `B`, `C2` and `D2`. Then I repeat the steps from 1 until the log-likelihood converges and I obtain optimal values for `A`, `B`, `C2` and `D2`.

*Is it correct to calculate Kalman filters for the entire training period before starting to calculate Kalman smoothers? Or should I, for example, calculate Kalman filters up till t=2, then Kalman smoothers for T=2, then Kalman filters up till t=3, then smoothers for T=3 etc.?*

3. Now I have values for `A`, `B`, `C2` and `D2` and can begin my testperiod, also 252 days. I don't update my estimates for `A`, `B`, `C2` and `D2`, but keep them constant. For each new observation I can compute Kalman filters (the same as in 2b). Finally I can compare `y(t)` to x`_{t|t-1}` for the training period.

My results look like this:

[image: My results]

While a paper by Chen, Ren and Lu have the following results:

[image: Their results]

NB: Not the same security... but the difference is obvious nonetheless.

Comment: How large is kt? I think it has quite a high value (numerical). Which happens because of C2 and D2 (I assume these are the noise covariance matrices).

Comment: It seems you're too confident on your measurements. You might want to increase D2 (a larger variance for measurement noise). That will trigger a lower kt.

Comment: I am screening a lot of stock pairs, but kt seems to be between 0.7 and 1.0 for the absolute majority of pairs. Furthermore, kt converges to a constant value extremely fast. As mentioned, I am using the EM algorithm to find the values of A, B, C^2 and D^2, and for this I am using a training period of a year (252 daily data points). Within the first 3-4 observations, kt has converged to a constant value.

Comment: The estimated C^2 lies between 0.0002 and 0.007, while the estimated D^2 lies between 0.000003 and 0.001. These are indeed the variances of the noise parameters.

Comment: I am just having trouble figuring out if I am doing something wrong with respect to estimating the variances... I tried simulating data from an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process and estimating the parameters using my EM code, and it caught the true values pretty well.

Comment: What happens when you choose C^2=0.0002 and D^2=0.001?

Comment: It is actually much better. Thanks for the insight :)

When C^2=0.0002 and D^2=0.001 it looks like this (for another pair and time frame, sorry for the confusion): 

![pic1](http://s12.postimg.org/7b01907u5/exhibit2.png)

Furthermore, if I make C^2 even smaller compared to D^2 (C^2=0.00002 and D^2=0.001) i get:

![pic2](http://s14.postimg.org/boislszwx/Exhibit3.png)

It seems that I am doing something wrong when using the EM algorithm. 
Can anyone check my procedure described in the main text?

Thanks a lot so far!

Comment: As a thumb rule (but I don't know if it applies in your case) we choose (in electrical engineering field) a D^2 of 1/sigma^2 (sigma being the standard deviation of the measurement noise calculated from the real observations). You can use a rough estimation. Then use that as an initial guess to fine tune it further more. The real challenge when designing Kalman filters is to determine C^2 and D^2 (the noise covariance matrices).

Comment: Do A, B, C^2, D^2 change throughout a simulation? If yes, by how much? If A, B, C^2 and D^2 are approximately constant then kt will converge to a constant relatively fast (because your process is linear).

Comment: Well, I use the EM algorithm to calculate A, B, C^2 and D^2. 
I guess initial values for all, then run the EM algorithm (described above) for these parameter values. Then calculate the log likelihood and update A, B, C^2 and D^2. I then repeat the EM algorithm for the new parameter values and calculate new LL... I stop when the LL has converged. I then use these final values for A, B, C^2 and D^2 as constants for the "trading period". That means that I dont update them in the Kalman filtering equations. Is this a mistake?

Best, 
Johan

Answer (score 0):

It seems that either you're underestimating the noise variance from the training data, or that your training data is not stationary in the period of your training window. try to increase the noise variance and you'll see that the filter actually smooths the time series. Your current under-estimation of noise variance leads the kalman filter to "forget" the past and give your last sample high weighting.

Comment: Hi and thanks a lot for your response. 
I think you are right, but don't know how to check it exactly? However, when I'm simulating normally distributed errors for the model, the EM algorithm captures the correct parameter values. However, if I try to simulate errors with other distribution (I tried this), the algorithm is no longer able to capture the correct values. This could be the issue. 
So I guess that the assumptions of the errors being normally distributed is too tough (at least for some pairs). Is this equivalent to the mean reversion assumption failing?

Answer (score 0):

checking it is quite easy. Increase the measurement noise/error variance (the matrix R in Kalman filter) and see how it affects the output.
If the model is no longer linear-Gaussian Kalman filter will not be optimal. However, it still should smooth your data, so start "training" it until it provides acceptable prediction.